# Signing a SamlAssertion in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, saml-2.0

I have a SamlAssertion in .Net 4.0.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.samlassertion.aspx

I need to sign it, then encrypt it, and POST it to a business partner. We are the Identity Provider and initiating the communication.

The sign method I've found on the web is expecting an XmlDocument to be sent as the parameter.  How to cast/convert the SamlAssertion to a signable xml document? Or is there a way to sign the assertion without having to cast/convert?

Answer (score 3):

Here is my three part tutorial on interoperable XML signing:

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2012/12/interoperable-xml-digital-signatures-c.html
http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2012/12/interoperable-xml-digital-signatures-c_20.html
http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2012/12/interoperable-xml-digital-signatures-c_4247.html

Pay attention to the part where the signing key information is appended to the signed document. This is what allows your recipient to easily verify whether the signature is valid or not and whether the key used to sign the message is acceptable or not. The recipient has to verify both! In particular, a valid signature is not enough as any certificate could be potentially used to generate a valid signature. On the other hand, you don't want the signature be generated with **any** key, rather, a key corresponding to the certificate known both to IdP and the Relying party.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this in two steps: First serialize the Assertion to XML, then sign it using the [`SignedXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml.aspx) class in the .NET framework.

Please be careful on what you are signing and encrypting: Do you want to sign/encrypt only the assertion or the entire Response message?

You might get some inspiration from a SAML2 library I wrote, where I have some methods for signing dummy messages in the unit tests: https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/blob/master/Kentor.AuthServices.Tests/SignedXmlHelper.cs

Comment: Thank you, Anders.  I will read through your library.  I am going to be upgrading to VS2012 to get .Net4.5 which has support for SAML2.0.  At the moment, when I try to sign the SAML1.0 Assertion I've created (VS2010 and .Net4.0) using the SignedXml class, the code is raising an error. I think it is because the ID attribute is named "AssertionID" not "ID". I am able to sign the document in its entirety, but not able to sign only the assertion node.

Comment: @RennishJoseph That's a new question, please don't post it as a comment but as a new question.